# Docker ate all free space and can't be started to free it?

Tags: 14.04, docker

Trying to run `sudo apt-get install -f` fails because I'm out of disk space:

```
udev                           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                          789M  812K  788M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/colorado--vg-root  139G   28G  105G  21% /
none                           4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda2                      237M  230M     0 100% /boot
/dev/sda1                      487M  3.4M  483M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1                      3.7T  2.3T  1.4T  63% /media/plex
```

I'm guessing this must be because of Docker, but now I'm not using it and I'd like to free up that space — looking at you, /dev/mapper. I tried using `- s devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.mountopt=discard` (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18867) but that fails:

```
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
WARN[0000] Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section. 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: exec: "mkfs.xfs": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Not sure where to go from here. Am I screwed?

Running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Comment: The only partition that appears to be full is `/dev/sda2` which is mounted at `/boot`. What is the exact error message you receive from `apt-get`?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get autoremove` work? I'm guessing you have some old kernels in there that could be removed.

Comment: `autoremove` wants the `linux-image` dependencies and recommends `-f`... which fails, because i'm out of disk space.

Comment: Ah. If you can get the exact package names that `apt-get autoremove` would remove, then you may be able to forcibly remove them with `dpkg`.

Comment: Cross posted (and put on hold) at [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301992/docker-eating-all-space-and-cant-get-rid-of-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has unlikely anything to do with docker. Docker normally stores its container info on `/var/lib/docker` and that is on your `/` mount point which has 105Gb free.

What is full is `/boot`, probably because of multiple old images. If you cannot uninstall these the normal way first look at what image you are running:

uname -r
then at what is under `/boot`:

ls -l /boot
and remove a `initrd.img....` and/or `vmlinux...` file **that doesn't match the kernel version that you are actually running**.

After you freed up some space you should be able to use `apt-get` again.

Comment: This fixed it! `/dev/sda2                      237M   78M  147M  35% /boot`